# List in Python - trying to eliminate doubling entries

Tags: python, list

I have a question that I didn't find answer anywhere on the internet (it's on python) :

I have a class named Pion and is described like this :

```
class Pion():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
```

in the main function, I'm creating a List of Pion :

```
PionList = []
```

I'm adding these values to this list :

```
PionList.append(Pion(3,4))
PionList.append(Pion(4,6))
PionList.append(Pion(3,4))
PionList.append(Pion(2,9))
PionList.append(Pion(4,6))
```

Now, I would like to find a way to clean up the list and only have unique combination x and y properties for each element of the list so at the end, my list will have 3 elements and not 5 (I want to eliminate the doubling entries (3,4) and (4,6) and only have one element with `Pion(3,4)`, one element with `Pion(4,6)` and one element with `Pion(2,9)`

I've tried to implement it in my code and I'm not able to visualize how I'll have to procede.

Any clues or possible solutions for this problematic?

Answer (score 4):

Using [`set`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set):

```
class Pion():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return 'Pion({0.x},{0.y})'.format(self)

lst = [Pion(3,4), Pion(4,6), Pion(3,4), Pion(2,9), Pion(4,6)]

seen = set()
newlst = []
for pion in lst:
    key = pion.x, pion.y
    if key in seen:
        continue
    seen.add(key)
    newlst.append(pion)

print(newlst)
```

output:

```
[Pion(3,4), Pion(4,6), Pion(2,9)]
```

If you define `__hash__` and `__eq__`, you can do it simpler way (The order of element is not guaranteed).

```
>>> class Pion():
...     def __init__(self,x,y):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return 'Pion({0.x},{0.y})'.format(self)
...     def __hash__(self):
...         return hash((self.x, self.y))
...     def __eq__(self, other):
...         return self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y
...
>>> lst = [Pion(3,4), Pion(4,6), Pion(3,4), Pion(2,9), Pion(4,6)]
>>>
>>> list(set(lst))
[Pion(3,4), Pion(4,6), Pion(2,9)]
```

Alternatively you can use `OrderedDict.fromkeys` (Orders are preserved):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(lst))
[Pion(3,4), Pion(4,6), Pion(2,9)]
```

Comment: The whole point of sets is not to have to check if the element is in the set - the way you've implemented it you may as well have made `seen` a list.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon: The point here is to make containment checking fast. With a list, containment checking would run in time proportional to the size of the list.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon, Using list, the time complexity become O(n^2).

Comment: @chthonicdaemon, See [TimeComplexity - Python Wiki page](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity).

Comment: I understand the time complexity argument, just seems like a waste to implement all of this checking if you're already using a `set` object which can do it for you.

Comment: @chthonicdaemon, What if you can't modify the class Pion?

Comment: @chthonicdaemon, + if original orders of items are important?

Comment: If order is important, the standard recipe is `OrderedDict.fromkeys(l).keys()`.

Comment: @user2357112, Thank you for comment. I added an `OrderedDict` example. BTW, you may know, OrderedDict is slow relatively.

Answer (score 1):

This is easily solved using sets. You simply have to make your Pion hash able and then you can do this:

```
class Pion():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __key(self):
        return (self.x, self.y)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.__key())

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.__key() == other.__key()

PionSet = {Pion(3, 4),
           Pion(4, 6),
           Pion(3, 4),
           Pion(2, 9),
           Pion(4, 6)}
```

You can use the `add` method to add more programattically.

Comment: You also need `__eq__`.

Comment: `PionSet` does contains 5 items. As  user2357112 commented, you need to implement `__eq__`, too.

Comment: Thanks for your comments - added this properly now.